# Rails, link_to, unable to pass on a value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I am trying to achieve an unordered list of "Categories" in which if you click on a particular Category, all the photos(jags) that belong to that Category show on the screen. My view that includes the categories is:

```
<div id = "Categories">
<h2>Categories</h2>
<ul><% @cat.each do |c| %>
    <li><%=link_to c.name, c,:controller => "category", :action => "show"  %>
    </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

my Category controller is:

```
def show
@jags = Jag.where("category_id = params[:id]")
   if @jags.empty?
     flash[:notice] = "No jags in this Category"
    end
end
```

and lastly my show view is:

```
<%= render 'nav' %>
<div><% @jags.each do |j| %>
<%=  image_tag j.image_url(:thumb)%>
<% end %>
</div>
```

The problem i am having is that I dont know how do i pass on my "particular category"(c) in the first view to the Category controller.

I tried making c an instance variable(@c) which apparently i cant do[formal argument cannot be an instance variable
    '); @cat.each do |@c| ;@output_buffer.safe_concat('].

If I run this code I get an SQLlite error[SQLite3::SQLException: near "[:id]": syntax error: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "jags"  WHERE (category_id = params[:id])].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use RESTful controllers this should be enough:

```
<div id = "Categories">
<h2>Categories</h2>
<ul>
<% @cat.each do |c| %>
    <li><%=link_to c.name, c  %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: I dont understand. How will link_to know where it is supposed to link the c.name to?

Comment: we pass `c` which is `Category` object

Comment: a couple of things i dont understand, 1. how does it know it is supposed to go the show action, 2. how can i pass on 'c' because its not an instance variable

Comment: Does my example works?
everything you should know for now is described here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects

Comment: I get this error "uninitialized constant CategoriesController"

Comment: hm. your controller name is Category not Categories which is not ok. 
Try to work with rails scaffolding, that will give you more understanding. Good point to start here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: I've got it to work and I understand Rails a little better. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you're getting the ID for the Category in the controller, then you can just do

```
@category = Category.find params[:id]
```

in your controller. Also, clean up your `link_to` helper as per below.